# Are `gcloud` and ADC credentials interchangeable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm actively using `terraform` and GCP as of late. But for `terraform` to work I need:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

for `gcloud` (I occasionally need to execute `gcloud` commands):

```
gcloud auth login
```

These 2 ways of authentication look pretty similar. Is it possible to somehow convert `application_default_credentials.json` into `credentials.db` or vice versa?

Comment: The credentials created by `gcloud auth login` are for the usage of the CLI command `gcloud` only. ADC is not a credential, it is a method of locating credentials. The files `application_default_credentials.json` and `credentials.db` are used for different purposes. I have written articles about both on my blog site (jhanley.com) including how to process `credentials.db` using SQLite. For Terraform, I recommend explicitly specifying a service account and not using default credentials search (ADC).

Comment: @JohnHanley ADC might be a strategy, but is it just me or is there something wrong with calling a strategy "something something credentials"? Anyways for the purpose of this question considering ADC credentials seems reasonable to me. Because `auth` obtains credentials for `gcloud`, `auth application-default` for other applications. And they are stored in different files. You didn't say exactly that they aren't interchangeable, but if you meant it, you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668750/52499). What's wrong with using ADC to run `terraform` locally?

Comment: 1) Yes, they are stored in different files. 2) Using explicit anything is preferable to using defaults which can be derived from multiple sources. ADC is intended for development and not for production environments. Using implicit credentials is fine for development, but the minute you must document and release projects to production, everything should be explicit and not implied.

Comment: 3) Another fine-grained point: gcloud auth should be user credentials. gcloud auth application-default should be a service account. There are subtle differences between those such as quota projects, API rate limiting, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Interesting point about explicit being preferable for production. But [the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started) says: "The preferred method of provisioning resources with Terraform on your workstation is to use the Google Cloud SDK [`gcloud auth application-default login`] as we mentioned earlier." They basically suggest a user account (supposedly) + `gcloud auth application-default login` (the preferred way) or a service account + `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Using a service account sounds like a better solution...

Comment: ...I don't know what are the risks, but at least according to the principle of least privilege. On the other hand safer solutions are often more complex (e.g. time to create a service account, grant permissions and keep them up-to-date). | Actually checking `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is also part of ADC. So technically even for production you're bound to use ADC. But yeah, this variable is checked first. So in fact providing the var makes ADC use only one source. | > gcloud auth application-default should be a service account \n Even for development?...

Comment: ...But they added `gcloud auth application-default login` for some reason... | All in all generally I agree with you. Your suggestions looks the safest. But there might be other concerns like time spent... maybe others. So I'd say one should keep your suggestions in mind, but make decisions based on the situation at hand. To add more details I run `terraform` in a `docker` container, as such I don't keep the credentials the whole time. The credentials disappear after I exit the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually they are.

Make sure you did both:

```
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

or this way (that's the first sign):

```
$ gcloud auth login --update-adc
```

After you did you have 2 relevant files:

```
~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json  # ADC
~/.config/gcloud/credentials.db                        # gcloud
```

Copy them to a temporary dir:

```
$ cd `mktemp -d`
$ cp ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json \
     ~/.config/gcloud/credentials.db \
     .
```

Create `credentials.db` from `application_default_credentials.json` and vice versa (replace `EMAIL` and `PROJECT_ID` with your data):

```
$ docker run --rm -itv "$PWD:/app" -w /app alpine:3.19 sh -euc "
    apk add sqlite jq
    sqlite3 credentials.db \"select value from credentials\" \
        | jq \"{client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, type}\" \
            > application_default_credentials2.json
    sqlite3 credentials2.db \"CREATE TABLE credentials (account_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value BLOB)\"
    sqlite3 credentials2.db \"INSERT INTO credentials (account_id, value) VALUES ('EMAIL', CAST(readfile('application_default_credentials.json') AS TEXT))\"
    # sqlite3 credentials2.db \"INSERT INTO credentials (account_id, value) VALUES ('EMAIL', '\`cat application_default_credentials.json\`')\"
"
```

Then try to use the resulting files (`credential2.db` and `application_default_credentials2.json`):

```
$ docker run -v "$PWD:/app" -w /app google/cloud-sdk:457.0.0-alpine sh -euc '
    cp application_default_credentials2.json \
       ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
    gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
'
$ docker run -v "$PWD:/app" -w /app google/cloud-sdk:457.0.0-alpine sh -euc '
    cp credentials2.db ~/.config/gcloud/credendials.db
    gcloud config set account EMAIL
    gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
    gcloud auth print-access-token
    gcloud compute instances list
'
```

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/19f292b2d77a9718c281a887e647b200).

Comment: Your answer is very interesting and I learned a few tricks I did not think of before. This weekend I will test this post and your other link. Thank you.